# Best practice securing SQL Database Credentials with PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I currently have a web pages which pull data from an SQL database and display it using php to handle the connection and query.

I am currently using this snippet in my PHP file to connect and pull data:

```
$conn = odbc_connect(
    "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=databasename", "username", "password");
if (!($conn)) { 
    echo "<p>Connection to DB via ODBC failed: ";
    echo odbc_errormsg ($conn );
    echo "</p>\n";
}
```

Does anyone see vulnerability with this and is there practice I should use?

Answer (score 1):

I would put code such as this into a PHP Class file, and model it after the DAO Pattern (Data Access Object).  Then, use the `require` or `require_once` directive on the script(s) that need to read/write to the DB.

This cuts down on the repetition and adheres to D.R.Y (Don't repeat yourself), when other scripts/code needs to read/write to the same DB, you'll already have a method in place to do so.

I would recommend against printing the error message to the screen.  By all means, log it to a file (or check the error logs to see what happened).

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to store the connection params/credentials in a directory that is not served to the public.  For example, the /var/www/html folder would not be a good idea.  Also if the connection params are in PHP, someone would have to know which file contains them, and then be running a web server to execute the file. Otherwise (worse-case) someone has gotten shell access to your server and can simply do a `cat` command on the file.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam T suggests, this type of code should definitely be captured in a separate file that is re-usable across your application (perhaps this is already the case - not clear from the details given).

If you look at any CMS system eg. WordPress, Joomla or Drupal, you will see they all store the DB credentials in plain text in a config.php file or similar, that gets read in early in the request processing cycle.

With respect to vulnerabilities though, ultimately, you have to place the login credentials somewhere that the PHP code can access it, so either it has to be stored in clear text in a PHP or text file that gets included or read in, or else obfuscated in some way, though generally this is a waste of time and effort.

Your best bet is to ensure the file containing the login credentials is suitably protected via filesystem permissions to prevent access from unauthorised prying eyes.

Comment: Thank you John, I think I understand and I think i'm in the ballpark.  I do store the connection info in its on separate file which is called by other php files.  Ultimately, what it comes down to are the file permissions.  I will look into this further.